# geode exception: org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.MessageTooLargeException: Message too large to send

Tags: gemfire, geode

geode exception: MessageTooLargeException: Message too large to send
Message has default size set and if client or server try to send message>default size , it throws this exception   org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.MessageTooLargeException: Message too large to send

Answer (score 1):

DEFAULT_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE = 1073741824;
this property value needs to be override to resolve this issue.
we are setting jvm system property using gemfire.client.max-message-size to desired size.
for example
-Dgemfire.client.max-message-size=2073741824

this needs to be similar on client and server side.

Comment: we had face this issue and there was not any proper explanation on google to get this fix. so putting here so it can be help to others who is upgrading gemfire version to geode latest